# Include the included html file in doxygen in the generated latex pdf

Tags: html, pdf, latex, doxygen

Alright, the question seems a bit convoluted. But here's what I am doing. I generate doxygen documentation from my commented code and then generate latex pdfs out of by configuring doxygen to do so. 
I have one small problem, when I include an html file using \htmlinclude, that link or file does not get included in the latex generated pdf.
How can I achieve this? i.e. Include the included html in doxygen in latex?

Answer (score 0):

`\htmlinclude` definitely won't do this.  From the manual: "*The command is equivalent to pasting the file in the documentation and placing **\htmlonly** and **\endhtmlonly** commands around it.*" - so any included with \htmlinclude will only appear in HTML output, not LaTeX.

If you want to insert verbatim HTML (i.e. you're quoting that file of HTML as an example, rather than wanting the HTML to be interpreted by Doxygen) then you could try`\verbinclude` instead.

Otherwise, I think you need to give a bit more detail about what it is you are trying to achieve.

Comment: \verbinclude doesn't do it for me. To be more precise, it's just an html table that i want to get included in latex through doxygen automatically.

Comment: @RichardMacwan Does the process work correctly if you copy the table into the file where you are currently using \htmlinclude?  Is doing that a substantial problem?  I appreciate it's undesirable from a modularity perspective but I think you're short of options.

Comment: It's just an autogenerated html file(with a table in it) which I wanted to use in my documentation. Manually copying the table creates some problems since it was autogenerated  and I would need to manually edit it which is the same as writing down the table manually in doxygen comments. So I guess I really am short of options :P

Comment: @RichardMacwan Can it be autogenerated as doxygen or markdown text instead of html?  In the doxygen case it won't be much different except perhaps to have a `@anchor` that your could `@ref` from the main text.  Alternatively, can you parse the autogenerated HTML to create a doxygen text file before running doxygen?  Hmm, this is all getting a bit tangled.

Comment: yes it is getting a bit tangled :) But it's not a huge requirement so I'd just put html text directly in doxgen next time. Thanks for the help.